Should [reference-materials] and [resources] be synonym-ized?
It looks like reference-materials is almost the same as resources.
Question: Should reference-materials and resources be synonym-ized?
The tag reference-materials has 19 questions:

What are some backgrounds and references to obsolete simplified Chinese characters?
Is there an official stroke order for each character?
Deeper meaning of 爲 (beyond one sentence definitions)
Has there ever been an English translation of 《輶軒》"Fangyan"?
Mandarin in Hunan Province
Where can I find 下江人's article《释四川话 (二)》from《旅行杂志》1945/7/18?
What does 論 mean in 時情天意枉論量？
Reference: 'hou' in Sichuanese meaning 'to eat'
Dictionary for Vietnamese to Chinese characters
Two-character homonyms with same meaning
新华字典 as CSV download available?
Analog of Hong Kong grade level for Chinese characters?
Semantic radical and dictionary header for 将
Translations from TCM (Traditional Chinese medicine)
Taiwanese Mandarin vs Mainland Mandarin
Are there any style guides for Chinese?
Resources for learning classical Chinese
Are children's books a good starting place for beginners?
Are there standard dictionaries for Chinese?


In this case, I think reference-materials is a useful synonym of resources.  I can't (currently) suggest the synonym, however:

Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag.

